# What is Mugen chewing?

Tags: samurai-champloo

[image: mugen chewing leaf]

What is Mugen chewing always sometimes he chews small sticks, some other times he chews long stems with leaves. Is that Japanese style? and what is that plant name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anime characters chewing on a blade of grass/toothpick is considered [a trope in anime](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OralFixation?from=Main.OralFixationFixation) and is *usually* attributed to the delinquent types.

> Sometimes a character will suck or chew on something as a form of
>   characterization. These range from **toothpicks and blades of straw or
>   grass** to lollipops and cigarettes.
>
> In anime, **having a piece of straw in one's mouth is a common depiction
>   of a banchou**, or juvenile delinquent gang-leader character.

Some other characters that have been noted to conform to this trope:

1. **Tetsuya Kusakabe** from  **Katekyo Hitman Reborn!**, a *delinquent* character.

[image]

2. **Ikki Takeda** from **History's Strongest Disciple Kenichi**, who was formerly *a member of a gang called Ragnarök*.

[image]

3. **Mifune** from **Soul Eater**, who's personality is described [like this](http://souleater.wikia.com/wiki/Mifune):

   *Often stoic in nature and staunch in attitude, Mifune tends be somewhat quiet in situations that do not directly involve him and remains mostly serious as well as being straight-forward..*

[image]

4. **Ash's Treecko** from  **Pokémon**, described as [*cool, calm, collected and serious*](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Ash%27s_Sceptile).

[image]

---

[**Wikia, on Mugen**](http://champloo.wikia.com/wiki/Mugen):
*Rude, lewd, vulgar, conceited, temperamental, and unhinged - Mugen is something of an antihero.*

Thus, it can be inferred that the "blade of grass in mouth" trope is a type of characterization that *mostly* represents a serious/delinquent sort of character.

---

The plant isn't usually of significance and isn't the same in every case unless explicitly stated. In a [Japanese page](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E6%AD%A6%E7%94%B0%E4%B8%80%E5%9F%BA) that describes **Ikki Takeda** from the second image above, the following is written with respect to the blade of grass.

> 常に葉っぱを口でくわえて...

which translates to "Always with a leaf in his mouth...", indicating that he's not chewing on any special plant.

As for what Mugen is chewing in the particular image posted, I'd guess it's bamboo.